# Gmail push notification empty history when Attached file exist

Tags: push-notification, gmail, gmail-api, webhooks

I'm using Gmail [push notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) in order to get user Gmail activities.
It works well but I noticed a weird behavior that prevent me from getting the user sent email attached files

When I'm getting a push notification to my server endpoint, I'm sending GET request of [user history list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) using the historyId I received

- when sending the history List request on email that sent **without** a file attachments I'm getting object response that contain the message Id

{"history":[{"id":"59237","messages":[{"id":"15eb563b63b660ed","threadId":"15eb563b63b660ed"}]}],"historyId":"59238"}

- but when sending the history List request on email that sent **with** file attachments **I'm not getting the message Id and without it I cant get that message details along with the file attachments**

  {"historyId":"59281"}

**what cause this behavior and what can I do to solve this problem?**